# How can i get the vocabulary list with with synonyms and antonyms columns to populate my SQLite Database?

Tags: android

I want to build a vocabulary app for android and i need word list file which contains words along with their synonyms,antonyms and their use. I just want to know whether is there any source to get such word list, because i am finding it hard to populate my database.

Comment: using sqlite you can't populate your file

Comment: It sounds like you want a thesaurus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to find a web thesaurus service that offers access to its API such as [Big Huge Thesaurus](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php).  You can get information from this site to populate a local database for offline usage.

Comment: I want Vocab List regarding to GRE Words not the complete thesaurus.I have tried to use wordnet too but couldn't find anything?
can u suggest something else?